# Rails "remote: true" works with link_to, doesn't work with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

My rails app uses UJS to submit forms all over the place, but for some reason I can't get it to work here.

I'm fairly sure I have UJS set up properly (as it works in other places):

```
#application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

#assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

In my view, I have both a `form_tag` and a `link_to`, both set to `remote: true`:

```
<%= form_tag apply_tag_applications_path, remote: true, method: :post do %>
  <%= submit_tag "FORM TAG SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to apply_tag_applications_path, remote: true, method: :post do %>
  <h1>LINK TO SUBMIT</h1>
<% end %>
```

Clicking the `link_to` works as expected (the request format is JS):

```
Started POST "/tag_applications/apply" for ::1 at 2017-05-30 11:10:51 -0400
Processing by TagApplicationsController#apply as JS
```

But clicking the `form_tag` submits via HTML:

```
Started POST "/tag_applications/apply" for ::1 at 2017-05-30 11:11:02 -0400
Processing by TagApplicationsController#apply as HTML
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the second one not to work as expected?

Comment: Have you tried `form_tag apply_tag_applications_path, method: :post, data: {remote: true}`?

Comment: Using `data: {remote: true}` instead of plain `remote: true` still didn't fix the issue, however I noticed in the HTML that is rendered using your suggestion (`data: {remote: true}`) caused a hidden field with an authenticity token to be added to the form. I don't see this hidden field with the code as per my quetion above.

Comment: post your routes and controller code, as well as show the name of the corresponding js file (should be whatever the controller's action name is.js.erb)

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you're referencing the jquery_ujs file in the layout or in assets.

```
#application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :jquery, :jquery_ujs %>

#assets/javascripts/application.js
require jquery.js
require jquery_ujs
```

Also, remote options will only work when you pass an object instead of path to form_for.

This will work

```
<%= form_for @apply_tag, remote: true, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "FORM TAG SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, I can verify that both of these references are in place (question edited to reflect this).

Comment: I've edited the answer. Basically, remote option will work when you pass an object instead of a path. Or you can send both using url option too.

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't working. Request is being received as HTML: 
`Started POST "/tag_applications" for ::1 at 2017-05-30 11:52:23 -0400`

`Processing by TagApplicationsController#create as HTML`

Comment: Did you changed form_tag to form_for? And also, make sure the object you pass is setted in the controller.

Comment: My view:
`<%= form_for @new_tag, remote: true, method: :post do %>
  <%= submit_tag "FORM TAG SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>`

My controller includes:
`@new_tag = TagApplication.new`

Still requests as HTML

Comment: Try this: `<%= form_for @new_tag, remote: true, method: :post do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "FORM TAG SUBMIT" %>
    <% end %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145487/discussion-between-gustavo-toro-and-greg-matthew-crossley).